# IAM Policy variables not recognised - ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a solution where every client that will use my service will have a sqs (which is in my AWS account). So in order that the client will be able to send messages and read messages from the queue, I want to use cognito with a single role that has variables, as there is a limitation on the number of roles that a single account can have.
I have created cognito user pool with an application, also created federated identity, role, policy and linked everything together.

the policy is

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
            "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch",
            "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXX:test-${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXX:test"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

the test client code is

```
const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
  console.log(`session token: ${session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()}`);
  const paramsCredentials = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'XXXX',
    Logins: {}
  };

  AWS.config.region = 'XXXX';
  paramsCredentials.Logins[
    `cognito-idp.${AWS.config.region}.amazonaws.com/XXXX`
  ] = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
    paramsCredentials
  );

  AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`got error - getting credentials. error: ${err}`);
    }

    const id = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
    console.log('Cognito Identity ID ' + id);

    const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
      region: AWS.config.region
    });
    const params = {
      QueueName: 'test-9ea2b895-2971-4ee2-b372-451bf2b19731'
    };
    sqs.getQueueUrl(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`got error getting url for queue, error: ${err}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`SQS url = ${data.QueueUrl}`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and I am getting an error of

> AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue: The specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it.
>   Blockquote

But when I change the queue to the test one, all is working fine. I have double checked the sub and it is the correct id

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` IAM policy variable will return `region:uuid` your queue name will be `test-us-east-1:9ea2b895-2971-4ee2-b372-451bf2b19731` which is a invalid SQS queue name(colon not allowed). So, it is not possible to restrict access to a queue named after that identity but you can create a policy limited to only a specific set of users of your application

Here is a blog from AWS on [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication Part 3: Roles and Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/)

```
  {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
            "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch",
            "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:XXXX:test"
        ]
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": [
                        "us-east-1:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456790ab"
                        ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: so is there a way to do it? as i want to give specific role per user on a single queue

Comment: updated the policy to restrict a user to a single queue but it's not dynamic